# Compact yet exact floating-point number formatting

Tags: json, lua, floating-point, tostring, ieee-754

Fixing a Lua JSON implementation, I replaced `"%.14g"` for number formatting with `"%.17g"` to counter loss of precision: Formatting 17 digits using `"%.17g"` always suffices to allow converting an IEEE 754 double (the default Lua number type) to a string representation which can be converted back to the exact number. However, this may result in ugly number formatting: `("%.17g"):format(0.1)` and `("%.17g"):format(0.3)` result in `"0.10000000000000001"` and `"0.29999999999999999"` respectively due to float inaccuracies. Clearly `%g` doesn't always use the shortest representation of a number in case there are two decimal representations that get rounded to the same float.

I'm currently considering the following hack for cleaner (more compact) number formatting: Use `%.17g` only if `%.16g` does not produce an exact representation, e.g.:

```lua
local function number_to_string(num)
    local compact = ("%.16g"):format(num)
    if tonumber(compact) == num then
        return compact
    end
    return ("%.17g"):format(num)
end
```

using this, `0.1` and `0.3` are converted to their more compact representations:

```lua
> number_to_string(0.1)
0.1
> number_to_string(0.3)
0.3
```

`tostring` produces compact number representations, but *does not preserve precision*; besides, it seems the reference manual does not guarantee that it uses any particular format:

```
> tostring(0.123456789101112)
0.12345678910111
> ("%.17g"):format(0.123456789101112)
0.123456789101112
```

Question(s):

- **Does this work in general**, or will there be Lua numbers where a more compact representation exists but this fails to find it?
- **Is there a more efficient way** of finding the compact number representation in Lua?

Comment: Prefer `%a` for hexadecimal notation; it is intended for exact input/output of floating-point values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not an option: 1. Lua 5.1 doesn't support it, 2. This is for *JSON*, which does not support hexadecimal float notation.

Answer (score 3):

> will there be Lua numbers where a more compact representation exists but this fails to find it?

Yes.
Denormalized numbers might have much less than 17 significant digits:

```
string.format("%.17g", 2^-1074)  -- 4.9406564584124654e-324
string.format("%.16g", 2^-1074)  -- 4.940656458412465e-324
....
string.format("%.2g", 2^-1074)   -- 4.9e-324
string.format("%.1g", 2^-1074)   -- 5e-324
```

Single-digit-approximation gives the same number:

```
5e-324 == 2^-1074                -- true
```

Comment: Good counterexample. How should I fix it? Simply trying all numbers of significant digits would be pretty bad performance-wise. I suppose I could do a binary search, but still, I wouldn't want 4-5 `string.format` and `tonumber` calls just for formatting a single number...

Comment: You need one `string.format` and 4-5 `tonumber`

Comment: How would I get away with one `string.format`? I need to try different precisions to see which works. [Here's a PoC](https://gist.github.com/appgurueu/44eae009b4b4d6c48af606647985578b).

Comment: All roundings are done manually, only `"%.17g"` is created by `string.format`

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff, start with `"%.17g", num`.  Then try less precise formats or other formats and convert that text back to a number.  If the number is the same as `num`, you have a shorter version.  Loop until failure.